# TypeError: 'BatchDataset' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
plt.figure(figsize = (15,15))
# data_files.take(count) : Creates a Dataset with at most 'count' elements(batch) from the dataset
for image, label in data_files.take(1): 
    for i in range(12):
        plt.subplot(3, 4,i+1) # many plots at a time =>subpots
        plt.imshow(image[i].numpy().astype('uint8')) #converting all data of image into numpy and than to integer type as they were in float.
        plt.title(data_files[label[i]])  # title of the class_name of image
        plt.axis("off") # Hide the values of graph
```

The output is:

```
ypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-e6bd849f1b25> in <module>
      6         plt.subplot(3, 4,i+1) # many plots at a time =>subpots
      7         plt.imshow(image[i].numpy().astype('uint8')) #converting all data of image into numpy and than to integer type as they were in float.
----> 8         plt.title(data_files[label[i]])  # title of the class_name of image
      9         plt.axis("off") # Hide the values of graph
     10 

TypeError: 'BatchDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

Please, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you are trying to use the square bracket notation ([]) on a BatchDataset object, which is not supported. To fix the problem, you need to convert the label tensor to a numpy array before indexing it with label[i].

Try the following instead:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
for image, label in data_files.take(1):
    labels = np.array(data_files)[label.numpy()] # convert label tensor to numpy array
    for i in range(12):
        plt.subplot(3, 4, i+1)
        plt.imshow(image[i].numpy().astype('uint8'))
        plt.title(labels[i])  # use numpy array to index the class names
        plt.axis("off")
```

Comment: ndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-72d3d611f94d> in <module>
      2 plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
      3 for image, label in data_files.take(1):
----> 4     labels = np.array(data_files)[label.numpy()] # convert label tensor to numpy array
      5     for i in range(12):
      6         plt.subplot(3, 4, i+1)

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed